# Does Qt5 support 10-bit displays?

Tags: qt, user-interface, opengl

I have 16-bit grayscale PNGs which I load into a QImage. Suppose that monitor, graphics card, drivers and operating system all support 10-bit per channel images.

If I inherit from QOpenGLWidget `class ImageLabelGL : public QOpenGLWidget` and draw my 16-bit grayscale image from `paintEvent` (below), will Qt show my image as 10-bit per channel or 8-bit?

```
void ImageLabelGL::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    //set up rect r
    p.drawImage(r, img);
}
```

Comment: 10 bits per color or 10 bit grayscale monitor?

Comment: Qt does not write directly to the screen, so the question relates to drivers, like OpenGL driver in your case (every system has it if there is OpenGL hardware support).